# Reduction of time for matrix multiplication of pixels

Tags: python, performance, matrix

This part of my code is taking 30 minutes to multiple 300 RGB and Depth images pixel by pixel. How can I reduce this time? This is just a part of big code but this taking lot of time.

```
def depth_to_xyz_and_rgb(uu, vv, dep):
    # t1.tic()
    # get z value in meters
    pcz = dep.getpixel((uu, vv))
    if pcz == 60:
        return
pcx = (uu - cx_d) * pcz / fx_d
pcy = ((vv - cy_d) * pcz / fy_d)

# apply extrinsic calibration
P3D = np.array([pcx, pcy, pcz])
P3Dp = np.dot(RR, P3D) - TT

# rgb indexes that P3D should match
uup = (P3Dp[0] * fx_rgb / P3Dp[2] + cx_rgb)
vvp = (P3Dp[1] * fy_rgb / P3Dp[2] + cy_rgb)

# t1.toc()

# return a point in point cloud and its corresponding color indices
return P3D, uup, vvp
```

Sample images.

[image: Color_image]
[image: Depth_image]

Comment: For code review you want to post all the code. For a question on time issue with your code maybe you want to post on Stack Overflow instead.

Comment: What version of python is this written in? Can you also fix your indentation, as the `return` statement is outside the function?

Comment: With the current indentation the code doesn't make sense. Please fix the indentation and, while you're at it, consider posting a bigger part of the code to make it easier on the reviewers. Can you tell us more about the variables used as well? Those variable names probably make sense to you, but less so for everyone else reading them. Can you share the expected output of 1 of the sample images?